# How to update nested mongodb document data in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a document in my collection like below. I want to update specific object value. Please solve this. How to update `isChecked : "0"`

```
    {
    "STUDENT_001": {
    "name": "name1",
    "hobbies": {
        "01": {
            "isChecked": "1",
            "name": "hobby - name"
        },
        "02": {
            "isChecked": "0",
            "name": "hobby-name"
        }
    }
    },
    "STUDENT_002": {
    "name": "name2",
    "hobbies": {
        "01": {
            "isChecked": "1",
            "name": "hobby - name"
        },
        "02": {
            "isChecked": "1",
            "name": "hobby-name"
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be like:

```
.update(
  query,
  new BasicDBObject(
    "$set",
    new BasicDBObject("STUDENT_001.hobbies.01.isChecked", "0")
));
```

here query to match the document. and `$set` is update the field in the path specified i.e `"STUDENT_001.hobbies.01.isChecked"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jayaram Pradhan, but problem is that STUDENT_001 is hard coded here, is there any way to use this dynamically.

Comment: with Mongo3: `(query, set("where.nested", valu))`

Answer (score 0):

```
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
        new Query(Criteria.where("STUDENT_001.hobbies.01.isChecked").is("0")),
        new Update()
            .set("Update field name", "Update value"),
        yourObject.class);
```